# how to stub require function in typescript/node with sinon

Tags: node.js, require, sinon

I am using sinon version 9.0.3 to test a function that uses the in-built `require` function to get the contents of a `package.json` file. The contents of this package.json file continually change between each deployment so I want to stub the result of the `require` function.

In my src code the require function is used as follows:

```
const packageJSON = require('../package.json')
```

In order to stub this, I have tried the following code (note in my test the value of property `a` is all I'm checking for:

```
const packageJSONStub = sinon.stub(module, 'require');
packageJSONStub.withArgs('../package.json')resolves( { a : 'b' });
```

However, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property require`.

Would anyone know the correct method for carrying out a stub of the in-built `require` function?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cannot stub the `require` function - instead mock the file that `require` refers to.